# How do I display a border around a QWebEngineView?

Tags: c++, qt, qwebengineview

I have a QGraphicsWidget which I am using to paint and display a number of items including a QWebEngineView using the QGraphicsProxyWidget.  I am able to load web content into QWebEngineView, but I would like to make the view contain a border.  I have used "setStyleSheet" to try to add a border, but this does not appear to work.  The following code is in the constructor of my QGraphicsWidget class to add the QWebEngineView:

```
 QWebEngineView * view = new QWebEngineView();
 view->setFixedWidth(700);
 view->setFixedHeight(200);
 view->setStyleSheet("border: 10px border-color: black");
 view->load(QUrl("qrc:/myresources/guidetext.html"));

 QGraphicsProxyWidget * proxyView = new QGraphicsProxyWidget(this);    
 proxyView->setWidget(view);
```

This is how it currently looks:
[image]
How I would like it to look like:
[image]

Comment: I assume you want a border around the browser window? That would be in the qml that creates the window that contains the browser

Comment: Yes, I would like the border around the browser window, but I am not using QML... just the code above.  These views are created at run time.

Comment: The first thing I notice is the bad stylesheet. Let me try to fix it and I will get back to you. Stay tuned.

Comment: Meanwhile try: `border: 10px solid black;`.

Comment: Sorry, didn't work.

Comment: Yep. I have already created a test project and I am trying to fix it.

Comment: Normally `view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground); view->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;"); view->setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);` should do the trick. However, it seems that the content of `QWebEngineView` does not respect the margins.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Problem

Normally, setting the [Qt::WA_StyledBackground](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#WidgetAttribute-enum) attribute, then the correct stylesheet and the content margins like that:

```
view->setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground);
view->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;");
view->setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);
```

should do the trick.

However, it seems that `QWebEngineView` does not respect the content margins:

[image: QWebEngineView covers the right and bottom border]

## Workaround

I would suggest you to make `QWebEngineView` child of another `QWidget` and style the parent widget instead.

## Example

Here is an example I have prepared for you of how to change your code in order to implement the proposed solution:

```
auto *proxyView = new QGraphicsProxyWidget();
auto *widget = new QWidget();
auto *view = new QWebEngineView(widget);
auto *l = new QVBoxLayout(widget);

l->addWidget(view);
l->setContentsMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

widget->setAttribute(Qt::WA_StyledBackground);
widget->setStyleSheet("border: 1px solid black;");
widget->setFixedWidth(700);
widget->setFixedHeight(200);

view->load(QUrl("qrc:/myresources/guidetext.html"));

proxyView->setWidget(widget);
```

## Result

Here is the result when loading Google:

[image: The whole border around QWebEngineView is visible]

Comment: Thank you once again...the solution worked perfectly!